# how to print numbers using for loop in java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, printf

I have one text box in which I take the value of `how many number do you want to print?` Now My question is, how can I use for loop so that the number which I want to print is equal to the number that I got from textbox? One more thing is that I want to print only three numbers in one line.

i.e. If I got 14 in my text box the result will look like below.

```
1  2   3 

4  5   6

7  8   9

10 11  12

13 14
```

Comment: would you like to share what you tried so far?

Comment: i have used two for loops but it prints the number in multiply of three. means if i enter 10 then it gives me 10 lines of the numbers from 1 to 30.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that you captured the value from the text box and saved it into a number:

This will print out the numbers as you specified:

```
public void print_numbers(int num) {

      int counter = 1;

      while ( counter <= num ) {

          System.out.print(counter);
          if ( counter % 3 == 0 ) {
              System.out.print("\n");
          }
          counter++;
      }
}
```